# How to not have duplicate combinations in 3SUM?

Tags: python

This is my code for 3Sum. I'm only approaching this naively since I'm fairly new to coding. I also am not writing this as a function.

```
nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]
nums.sort()
for i in range (len(nums)):
    for j in range (i+1, len(nums)):
        for k in range (j+1, len(nums)):
            if nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k] == 0:
                nums_0 = [nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]]
                print(nums_0)
```

Expected output: [-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0, 1]

Comment: Naively you could generate all possible results and then remove the duplicates from them.

Comment: Untested idea: For each loop you could remember the last value and if the same value appears again, skip the loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better solution, but if you want something without duplicates, [set](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) should be the first thing you think about. Store your solutions in a set (but use tuples instead of lists, i.e. `nums_0 = (nums[i], nums[j], nums[k])`).:

```
nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]
nums.sort()

solutions = set()
for i in range (len(nums)):
    for j in range (i+1, len(nums)):
        for k in range (j+1, len(nums)):
            if nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k] == 0:
                nums_0 = (nums[i], nums[j], nums[k])
                solutions.add(nums_0)

for s in solutions:
    print(s)
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! I was really discouraged when I couldn't find how to put all of my output in to 1 list and return something that is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

My solutions:

```py
def _3sum_alg(numbers):
    nums = sorted(numbers)
    result = []
    for ia, a in enumerate(nums[:-2]):
        for ib, b in enumerate(nums[ia+1:-1], ia+1):
            for c in nums[ib+1:]:
                if a+b+c == 0:
                    result.append((a, b, c))
    return result


def _3sum_alg_lstcomp(numbers):
    nums = sorted(numbers)
    return [(a, b, c)
            for ia, a in enumerate(nums[:-2])
            for ib, b in enumerate(nums[ia+1:-1], ia+1)
            for c in nums[ib+1:]
            if a+b+c == 0]
```

My hints:

- It's better for your function to return the result and print it outside the function.
- To iterate over collection items, use `for i in some_collection: print(i)`, which is equivalent to `for i in range(len(some_collection)): print(some_collection[i])`.
- `enumerate(some_collection)` allows you to iterate over pairs of `(index, element)`.
- `some_collection[a:b]` returns a copy of `some_collection` that starts at index `a` and ends at index `b-1`.
- `sorted` returns a sorted copy of the list, while `.sort` sorts the original list (it's not necessary to get the right result).
- list comprehension is some faster that for loop and more "pythonic"

Comment: I like the list comprehension solution. You can switch to set and set comprehension to remove duplicates from the solution. And I'd avoid using `nums[... : ...]` because it (as you mentioned) creates a duplicate of part of the list on every iteration which is suboptimal.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - my code isn't optimized at run time. My code is optimized at write time and readability.
If i wanted to write fast apps, i would write it in c#, c++ etc.
I like pythonic way and had never in my life performance issue, so when i must write an app, i just write the app but when i need to create performance-focused app i will look for another tool.